# regex that strip unclosed <

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regex to use in php (maybe with preg replace?) that strips in a text all unclosed `<` and ONLY unclosed and all the unopened `>` and ONLY the unopened.

Some examples:

## 1

```
<name> aaaaaa bbbbb <  aagfetfe <aaaa/>
to
<name> aaaaaa bbbbb   aagfetfe <aaaa/>
```

## 2

```
<<1111>sbab  < amkka <pippo>
to
<1111>sbab   amkka <pippo>
```

## 3

```
<1111> aaaa <    thehehe  > aaaaaa <ciao>
to
<1111> aaaa <    thehehe  > aaaaaa <ciao>
```

## 4

```
<1111> aaaa   thehehe  > aaaaaa <ciao>
to 
<1111> aaaa   thehehe   aaaaaa <ciao>
```

## 5

```
<1111> aaaa   thehehe  < aaaaaa
to 
<1111> aaaa   thehehe   aaaaaa
```

I really cant do it its too difficult for me.

Comment: maybe just replace `SPACE>` with `SPACE` and the `<SPACE` with `SPACE`?.

Comment: I'd ask the same question but about parameters. Right now my problem is that I get things like `<a href="http:/... <a href="#">Read more</a>` and it messes my whole HTML up. Any idea for parameters? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
$s = preg_replace("/<([^<>]*)(?=<|$)/", "$1", $s); # remove unclosed '<'
$s = preg_replace("/(^|(?<=>))([^<>]*)>/", "$1", $s); # remove unopened '>'
```

Do you understand why?

Comment: Very nice - took me a few minutes to grok that.

Comment: i like stackoverflow You are the bEST

Answer (score 3):

For unclosed `<`, you can replace `<(?=[^>]*(<|$))` by an empty string. It matches all `<` which are not followed by a closing `>` before the next `<` or the end of the line. "*not followed by*" is a [positive lookahead](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html#10).

For unopened `>`, you can replace `((^|>)[^<]*)>` by `$1`. It matches text which starts with an `>` (or the line start), does not contain `<` and ends with a `>`. `$1` represents everything except the last `>`.